# Parsing JSON data in Swift3

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I am trying to parse JSON data in Swift3. When I try to print the whole `jsonResult` works fine printing all the JSON file. However, when I try to parse it I am facing issues.

This is the console output of my JSON file:

```
{
    city =     {
        coord =         {
            lat = "37.323";
            lon = "-122.0322";
        };
        country = US;
        id = 5341145;
        name = Cupertino;
        population = 58302;
    };
}
```

This is my code to parse the file:

```
if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? NSDictionary{
                print(jsonResult) //this prints all the file OK
                if let city = jsonResult["city"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                    if let country = city["country"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                        print(country) //this is not printing anything
                    }
                }
```

I've tried slightly different ways but I could not find a solution. I can't understand what the problem is. Can anyone give me a hand? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The value of the "country" key is *not* a dictionary ...

Comment: Hi @MartinR if I use a `String` is not working either

Comment: You should use native Swift structs, namely Dictionary and Any instead of NSDictionary and AnyObject.

Comment: Recommended reading: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"country" key in your json is not a dictionary thats why you are not getting any output.

Try below code it will work

```
if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? Dictionary<String:Any>{
            print(jsonResult) //this prints all the file OK
            if let city = jsonResult["city"] as? Dictionary<String, Any>{
                print(city["country"]) // to check what is the output
                if let country = city["country"] as? String{
                    print(country) //this is not printing anything
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've tried before with using String and did not work. That's why I was getting confusion.

Comment: `if let country = city["country"] as? String{
                    print(country) 
                }` I was using String before and did not print anything. Now I have exactly copied and pasted this and now is working. I undo to double check my previous code and was the same. Probably when I build the app the second time fixed the issue. Don't know what to think. Thank you again for the clarification anyway!

Answer (score 2):

see @MartinR 's note. He is absolutely right and based on this is also @Nishant Bhindi 's answer.

**WARNING !!!!**

from [JSON ORG](http://www.json.org)

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, **wrapped in
>   double quotes**, using backslash escapes.

It seems, that what You try to parse in not a valid JSON ...

Comment: What OP shows as "fragment of my JSON file" is **not JSON.** It is the output of `print(jsonResult)`, i.e. the output of printing a **NSDictionary,** and that's why there are no double quotes.

Comment: @MartinR he wrote "Hi MartinR if I use a String is not working either", but maybe, I didn't understand him and he tried conditionally cast as a String something else :-)